# Flow wait Element time frame

Tags: visual-workflow, wait-element

When I am using a wait element in a flow, what are some of the options I could use for the time frame? I don't see it clearly explained anywhere, but all the documentation seems to indicate waiting days to continue a flow. I'm wondering if you can set it to wait 30 seconds or 1 minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Days or hours are your options

See offset unit on relative or absolute time alarms under the flow event type documentation page

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=vpm_designer_elements_waitevents.htm&language=en_US

Where they say

Manually enter Days or Hours. You can’t use a merge field or flow resource for this value.